# How to search through the keys of an object and get the values of matching keys

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How can i make a search engine out of an object?

Example:
how can i use

{
onE:"two",
three:"four",
wOn:"too"
},

do something with the phrase "ON",
and somehow return ["two","too"]?

Edit:
if i may alter this question slightly, how can i make the most alike keys' values go first? I'm also using spaces in the keys.

new Example:
in:

{
"one one zero":"0"
"zero":"1"
"one two":"2"
"one one":"3"
}

out:

["3","0","2"]

Comment: You're looking for fuzzy matching. One example is [Fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/). More generally, the concept involved is the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```js
var object = {
    onE: "two",
    three: "four",
    wOn: "too" 
};

var array = [];

Object.keys(object).filter((key) => key.match(/On/i)).forEach((key) => {
    array.push(object[key]);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Basically, get the keys from the *object*, and filter them on the basis of regex to match `ON` in the key. Once we have the filtered keys, we *forEach* loop them to push their values into the empty `array`.

Comment: BTW you could have done also with the map and just return `object[key]`. For more details you can see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

```js
var object = {
    onE: "two",
    three: "four",
    wOn: "too" 
};


const result = Object.entries(object).reduce((accum, current) => {
  const [key, value] = current;
  if (key.match(/On/i)) {
    return [...accum, value]
  }
  return [...accum]
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

An alternative solution using `entries` and `reduce`, avoiding `push` which avoid side effects

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can simply get keys of an object using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and push the value of an object whose key contains `on` in it using regex

```
/on/i
```

```js
var object = {
  onE: "two",
  three: "four",
  wOn: "too",
};

const result = [];

for (let key of Object.keys(object)) {
  if (key.match(/on/i)) result.push(object[key]);
}

console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also do with `Object.keys`, `filter`, and `map`

```js
var object = {
  onE: "two",
  three: "four",
  wOn: "too",
};

const result = Object.keys(object)
  .filter((key) => key.match(/On/i))
  .map((k) => object[k]);

console.log(result);
```